# requestSingleUpdate doesn't work :(

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have the following code:

```
SosServiceListener mlistener = new SosServiceListener(this);

manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// getting network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = manager.
                            isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

String provider;
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
    provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
} else {
    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
}
manager.requestSingleUpdate(provider, mlistener, null);
manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

but the SosServiceListener is never called :( any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String provider;
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
    provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
} else {
    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
}
```

is GPS enabled on the device, with Satellite option set in Security section of mobile settings? because  you are assuming that GPS_PROVIDER is enabled, just because NETWORK_PROVIDER is disabled? which is not accurate ...

also `manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` will return `Location` object directly and will not result a call to callback methods in the listenet...

so you need to use either one of them...